# eclipse for loop assign button strings

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to develop an Android app of a simple sound board, which will play several long sounds, and only one at a time, not simultaneously.  I have the sound part playing great.  I want to assign text for each button.

I have a strings.xml set up like so:

```
<string name="quote01">quote01</string>
<string name="quote02">quote02</string>
<string name="quote03">quote03</string>
```

In my main.xml, I have my buttonIds set up like this:

```
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.button01, R.id.button02, R.id.button03, 
        R.id.button04, R.id.button05, R.id.button06, 
        R.id.button07, R.id.button08, R.id.button09, 
        R.id.button10, R.id.button11, R.id.button12, 
        R.id.button13, R.id.button14, R.id.button15, 
        R.id.button16, R.id.button16, R.id.button17, 
        R.id.button18, R.id.button19, R.id.button20, 
        R.id.button21, R.id.button22, R.id.button23, 
        R.id.button24, R.id.button25 };
```

I could just assign the button text like this to get it to work:

```
Button s01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01); 
s01.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote01));
Button s02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02); 
s02.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote02));
Button s03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button03); 
s03.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote03));
```

But I’d rather use a loop to avoid repetitive code.  I have a non-working loop like the below:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) { 
>     Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]); 
>     soundButton.setText(this.getString(R.string.buttonIds[i]);
> }
> ```

But in the 3rd line above, buttonIds can’t be resolved to a field.  I have tried putting brackets or parantheis around the buttonIds[1] but my syntax isn’t right.  I am sure this is a super easy question, but it is illuding me.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!
Maytag87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
Resources res = getResources();
for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) { 
    Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]); 
    soundButton.setText(res.getIdentifier("quote" + (i < 10 ? "0" + i : i), "string", getPackageName()));
}
```

Also your Strings set start from `quote01` and the loop starts from `i = 0`, so you have to synchronize the two values.

Comment: Thanks!  I cant complile with the two semicolons at the end, but if I take out the one in the middle:soundButton.setText(res.getIdentifier("quote" + (i < 10 ? "0" + i : i), "string", getPackageName())); then it compiles.  Hover the app get a force close.  Getting closer though, I can feel it!

Comment: @user1362308 I've put an extra `;` that should have been removed. Your strings start from `quote01`, `quote02` etc and the for loop starts from `i = 0` so at the start you'll have `quote00`. Either modify the strings to start from `quote00`, `quote01` etc or make the loop start from `i = 1` and continue until `i <= buttonsIds.length`.

Comment: Yes, setting the strings file to start at quote00 did the trick, worked flawlessly!  That is some cool code, thanks so much!  Appreciate the help and question answered!!!

Comment: Taking forward @Luksprog's observation, you can also do it this way : soundButton.setText(res.getIdentifier("quote" + ((i+1) < 10 ? "0" + (i+1) : i+1), "string", getPackageName()));

Comment: Okay. So you settled for renaming your strings. A better approach indeed :)